# Commands run as Job print status of the job intermittently

Tags: powershell, jobs, invoke-command, start-job

When I run certain commands (`Invoke-Command` or `Start-Job`) as background jobs, PowerShell sometimes prints the status of the job when starting the job.

For Example (simplified command here):

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $my_ip -FilePath "my_script.ps1" -ArgumentList $param_1 -AsJob
```

This command prints the whole `my_script.ps1` file to the console along with the start status like:

```
State          : Running
PSComputerName : 192.168.50.50
RunspaceId     : 0c83a64d-318e-43c8-9bdb-68893eeb96c9
HasMoreData    : True
StatusMessage  :
Location       : localhost
Command        : <whole contents of my_script.ps1 printed here>
JobStateInfo   : Running
... <some more status info>
```

I'm running a huge set of scripts and for some reason, changing the `$param_1` value alters the print behavior between printing job start summary (`Format-Table`-like output) and output that's shown above.

I've only been able to change how the output is printed (between the two options above) by changing where the parameters are declared.

This might be a bug in PowerShell, but I'm not sure. It is infuriating when the whole script file is printed on the console and the actual debug prints become difficult to spot.

Answer (score 0):

Starting a job returns a reference to the job object, which is what you're seeing in the output. Either discard it:

```
Inovke-Command ... -AsJob | Out-Null
[void](Invoke-Command ... -AsJob)
```

or capture it in a variable, so you can use it later:

```
$job = Invoke-Command ... -AsJob
```